# Why am I getting OSError when joining multicast group in Python?

Tags: python, networking, firewall, multicast

I am trying to join a multicast group with the following python (3.8) script:

```
    recvSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
    recvSocket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    recvSocket.bind(('', 5007))
    mreq = struct.pack("4s4s", socket.inet_aton("239.0.0.107"), socket.inet_aton("127.0.0.1"))
    recvSocket.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)
```

This works perfectly fine on one laptop, but the exact same code returns the following error on a different machine. Both are running Windows 10:

```
OSError: [WinError 10042] An unknown, invalid, or unsupported option or level was specified in a getsockopt or setsockopt call
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this a firewall issue?